# Simplify if else condition with ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am having the following code.

```html
if ($auth->user()){
    echo $session->getDetails('username');
} else {
    echo 'world';
}
```

I found out that I can make it simple by using the ternary operator, so I modified the code above to get something like this:

```html
($auth->user() ? $session->getDetails('username') : 'world');
```

The problem I am facing is the portion `$session->getDetails('username')` is not displayed. Kindly help me solve it

Comment: Does it work with the original `if` version? Ensure the `$auth-user()` works the same in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `echo` or assign a variable, so:

```
echo ($auth->user() ? $session->getDetails('username') : 'world');
```

or

```
$username = $auth->user() ? $session->getDetails('username') : 'world';
echo $username;
```